# error while trying to install react-native -floating-action

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

when I'm trying to install some package
like:
react-native-floating-action

or:

`react-native-action-button`

I'm running the

`npm i react-native-floating-action --save`

and when I run `react-native link`

i get this error:

```
PS C:\Projects\projectname> react-native link
rnpm-install info Linking assets to ios project
rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null

TypeError: Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null
    at Object.linkAssetsIOS [as copyAssets] (C:\Projects\projectname\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\link\ios\copyAssets.js:24:41)
    at C:\Projects\projectname\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\link\link.js:104:12
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at linkAssets (C:\Projects\projectname\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\link\link.js:94:28)
    at C:\Projects\projectname\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\link\link.js:171:30
```

these are my versions:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.1
 npm --version
6.4.1

 expo --version
2.6.14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found the problem,

I needed to run `react-native upgrade`, and had a different version of react-native in the package.json from the node_modules

writing ^0.57.8 (current react-native version) on the packge.json:

```
"react-native": "^0.57.8",
```

running `npm install`

setting a name for the project in the package.json:

`"name":"somename"`

and running

```
react-native upgrade 
react-native link
```

everything was ok

seems to me that it's always a matter of versions with react-native errors

Answer (score 1):

Expo does not support linked binaries. If you require linked binaries, you must first [Eject from Expo to ExpoKit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject) or initialize your project using `react-native init MyProjName`

## Reference

> If you know that you'll eventually need to include your own native code, Expo is still a good way to get started. In that case you'll just need to "eject" eventually to create your own native builds. If you do eject, the "Building Projects with Native Code" instructions will be required to continue working on your project.
>
> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me:**

npm update

react-native link